# Delay windows update prompt indefinitely

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have Windows 7 pro and too often I get the prompt to update Windows and restart. As I do not  want to shutdown and restart my PC too often, I would like to be able to "kill the prompt". The problem is I cannot do that and eventually I end up pressing "update and restart" accidentally at the most inopportune time

Comment: You could always upgrade to Windows 8 which provides you 48 hours before it forces you to install it.  It won't even ask you to do it only provide you a passive notification it wants to install an update.  Since I already know how you feel about Windows 8 ( more then likely ) the alternative is to not install updates automatically.

Comment: Why don't you just turn off automatic updates and update Windows when it's convenient for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always just stop the Windows Update service.

1. Open the services management snap-in by executing `services.msc`.
2. Find the **Windows Update** service and stop it.

   [image]

Comment: +1 for teaching me something, but "Stop" button is disabled in my case

Comment: @zencv What options do you have? What do the contents of the service properties look like?

Comment: You may have to run as administrator in order to get this option.  Navigate to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> right click on services and select "Run as Administrator"

Comment: Would the service be re-enabled upon shutdown restart?  I'd recommend following @joeqwerty's suggestion.  This is just a patch and it sounds like you really just want to turn off updates.

Comment: @LoganGoesPlaces Yes. As long as the startup type is set to **Automatic**, the service will automatically be started when Windows starts.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off automatic updates and run Windows Update when it's convenient for you.

[image]